# Designing exceptions in a c# application

Tags: c#, exception

When designing an application, you have two options how to design the exceptions (imo):

- You either create specific exceptions for specific cases and inherit them from System.Exception or some other child System exceptions.
- Or you create a base exception for your application which inherits probably from System.Exception, like MyAppException : System.Exception, and then you inherit all of the custom exceptions from that base exception.

I will not ask which approach is better in general because I do not think there is a clear answer. However, I would like to know which approach is more suitable for which applications, e.g. one is better for a winforms application and the other for a class library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no clear answer. No matter the type of application, there are cases where it is better to throw a "generic" application (possibly containing the specific one as an InnerException), and there are cases where it makes sense to inherit from an existing exception.

It's more important to consider who is going to catch the exceptions and what he should be able to do with them.

Comment: Well, I was hoping that there could be found certain patterns in the who-what relationship or at least some questions that one could answer himself/herself to help to sort out the thoughts.

Comment: Indeed, I was hoping on some clarification either.

Comment: Think about who is going to catch the exceptions and what he can do. If you are doing range checks etc, an ArgumentException is more than enough and all anyone can do is log it. On the other hand, if a credit card fails to validate, you should throw a specific exception with status codes and explanations that will allow someone further up the stack to decide what to do - try another bank or reject the customer?

Comment: I give up, you are probably right. Imho it is usual that an application does not define such a common exception because usually you catch all exceptions somewhere and log them and show user some "sorry" message, and on the other hand a library would define such an exception to enable its users catching the exception from the library. At least that is how I would probably do it.